# Python NAT Server

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, nat

I'm looking for a program to turn my computer into a NAT, preferably written in Python, that I can play with and modify for some research I'm taking part in.

We need to try and monitor a network's traffic and find some data inside the TCP packets, and as a proof-of-concept we want to use Python for its simplicity.

Do you know of anything like this? Would we have to write one from scratch?

Thanks,

Dvorak

Comment: This is a bad idea. Use a real router to do routing. Use a network tap to do interception. Don't mix the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into using the [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) library - you'll have to effectively implement both a client + server side in one, but that shouldn't be too hard.